# Automation Anywhere - Loop Each Email Message on Server

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

I am new on Automation Anywhere and I need some help.
I have a robot that loops through an email account to get the subject of the emails and then uses its information on other system. If a new email enters the box while the robot is running it seems to get lost and enters an infinite loop.
To better tackle this problem I am trying to understand how the email command works. Anyone knows if it get all emails on the box, keeps them in memory and then loops through those messages? Or does it access the box every time the loop restart and get the email on the top of the box?

Comment: Could you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got an email while the loop is running it will not be available on the loop.
The robot can read that email in the next run.

It doesn't store the emails on the memory, but it does require internet connection, so my conclusion is it stores the message/email id.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer made me realize that the problem wasn't in the email loop.